# executing copy command in a batch file

Tags: windows, outlook, batch-file, copy, dns

I'm using a windows copy command to perform auto file backup of Microsoft outlook files for a domain users.
the problem exists after 6 month of using this batch file is that the .pst file size for each user is growing and the copy operation is getting too long to complete.

i want to know are there any way to copy only the changed bits in the .pst file couse what i'm doing is copying the whole file each time a user login.

```
copy  C:\"Documents and Settings"\%USERNAME%\"Local Settings"\"Application Data"\Microsoft\Outlook\ \\storage\folder1\folder2\%USERNAME%\%DESTDIR% /y /v
```

thanks

Comment: I recommend you look at rsync

Answer (score 1):

This page might help you in doing that : [link](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Answer (score 0):

In a word: with the regular Windows `copy` command, no.

You've a few alternatives, though. Probably the best is to ask your users (or get your administrator) to reduce the size of the mailbox.

Another is to try the `robocopy` utility, which is part of the [Windows Server Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) and which replaces `xcopy` in versions of Windows above Server 2008 R2. In my experience this is a little faster. It also includes an option to skip the copy if the file hasn't changed, which may help if your users only use email infrequently.

`rsync` (details [here](http://rsync.samba.org/), Windows version [here](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)) does a true differential copy, so only the changed bytes between the files are copied. However this needs to be installed as a Windows service on the listening side and needs to be installed as a program on each client.

Comment: i will try the robocopy utility. we are running windows server 2003.

do you have any other alternatives for performing a fast file copy to all domain users. i mean performing a backup automatically using any other way